# Class running when I open VS 2012

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm working on Visual Studio 2012, on a .NET project.
I have a class that pops up a window asking the user for input. The window isn't set to show up at start-up.

Whenever I load my project, before I even build it, that class starts shows up.
When I run my program using the exe file, I don't have the same problem.

Does anybody know how I can prevent it from happening?

Thanks

Comment: I presume that this is a form?  What is in the forms constructor?

Comment: Use the DesignMode property to prevent code from running at design time.